# How to make figures on a bar chart bold in plotly express without changing the original pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I have created a bar chart and I need to make only the numeric figures on top of the bars appear bold. I am not allowed the modify the original pandas dataframe. I am using plotly.express.

Attempt 1- Code snippet for creating bar chart -

```
import plotly.express as plt
smokersSum=df.groupby('City')[['Male','Female']].sum().reset_index()
fig=px.bar(smokerSum,x='City',y=['Male','Female'],text=['Male','Female'],text_auto=True)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='<b>%{text}</b>', textposition='outside')
fig.show()
```

Attempt 2- Code snippet for creating bar chart -

```
import plotly.express as plt
smokersSum=df.groupby('City')[['Male','Female']].sum().reset_index()
fig=px.bar(smokerSum,x='City',y=['Male','Female'],text=lambda row: f"{row['Male']}, {row['Female']}",text_auto=True)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='<b>%{text}</b>', textposition='outside')
fig.show()
```

None of these worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To automatically annotate numbers in a bar chart, simply specify `text_auto=True`. Then if you want to qualify that annotation, specify the y-axis value in the way you have set up. Since no data was provided, I took a guess and used data from a similar [reference](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#indexing-by-geojson-properties).

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.election()[:10]

fig = px.bar(df, x='district', y=['Coderre','Bergeron','Joly'],  text_auto=True)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='<b>%{y}</b>', textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(height=500)
fig.show()
```

[image]